# Inject SwiftMailer into symfony2 service

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, swiftmailer

I have a service which extends UserManager, so when I do:

```
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setSubject('~')
            ->setFrom('~')
            ->setTo('~')
            ->setBody('~', 'text/html');
        $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
```

I get the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method My\MyBundle\Service\ServiceClass::get()
```

I know this is because I need to inject the swiftmailer into here, but how?
(usually the service class extends 'Generic' so the swift mailer is included.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Depending on what kind of service file you are using you need to inject it into your service directly like you said.

XML:

```
<services>
        <service id="sample.service" class="%sample.service.class%">
            <argument type="service" id="mailer" />
        </service>
</services>
```

YAML:

```
services:
    sample.service:
        class:     %sample.service.class%
        arguments: [@mailer]
```

You can simply grab the service in your constructor like this.
Or if you really want, you can inject the `service_container`. But that's really dirty, since you can just inject the services you need.

Injection the `service_container` is only needed if you need a dynamic service call.

Comment: I have added the service in the .yml file but I'm not sure how to call it in in the constructor of the class?

Comment: Simply add a parameter to the constructor, like `public function __construct($mailer)` and then e.g. assign it to a private property in the constructor body.

Comment: a dummys guide: Add the service as answer above. Then add to the constructor as above comment. then add `$this->mailer = $mailer;` in the constructor. You can then use: `$this->mailer->send($message);`

Answer (score 1):

In services.yml (symfony 4 example)

```
mailer:
    class: \Swift_Mailer

myClass:
    class: x\x
    arguments:
        - "@mailer"
```